# mod_mono on windows

Tags: asp.net, .net, apache, mono, mod-mono

I am trying mod_mono on apache 2.2.x running on a win7 box – followed [the steps described here](http://anmar.eu.org/mono/mod_mono/).

The module loads Ok, but I can't run my ASP.net application (404). Does anybody have any suggestions or an example configuration that works? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the relevant portions of your httpd.conf?  If you're getting a generic 404, it could be a problem with your VirtualHost entry, but that's just a random guess since I can't see the actual config.

Comment: Hi Kris, the configuration used was the one in the link provided. I checked the VH with a static page and works, so I reckon there is something wrong with the module itself.

Comment: how did you get mod_mono.so?

Answer (score 1):

My working config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:\web\mysite"
    MonoServerPath mysite "c:\mono\usr\bin\mod-mono-server2.exe"
    MonoApplications mysite "/:c:\web\mysite"

    <Directory "c:\web\mysite">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        MonoSetServerAlias mysite
        SetHandler mono
        DirectoryIndex default.aspx index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am curious how did you get mod_mono to compile, can you share what compiler, mono version, etc used?

Answer (score 1):

I found a good [tutorial](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2008/07/24/configuring-and-running-mono-asp-net-3-5-ajax-net-on-linux-computers.aspx) for you.

Example mono configuration:

```
MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono_server2
Alias [D] “[P]”
AddMonoApplications default “[D]:[P]”
<Location [D]>
SetHandler mono
</Location>
```

Another example:

```
MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono_server2
Alias /MySite “/srv/www/htdocs/MySite”
AddMonoApplications default “/MySite:/srv/www/htdocs/MySite”
<Location /MySite>
SetHandler mono
</Location>
```

Comment: The tutorial is very good (therefore the vote), unfortunately it is intended for Linux. How about the same for windows. I was not able to compile mod_mono (2.8) so looking forward for anyone that can share some tips.